# BottomNavigationView not showing at bottom, but at top instead

Tags: android

My menu is not sticking to the bottom. I have a menu, in a BottomNavigationView. The navigation view is included in a layout. I tried with setting gravity to bottom, setting constraints, alignparentbottom, still it is showing at the top of the layout. Below is the code for my menu, navigation, and my layout.

I added a picture to illustrate the problem:

[image]

My Menu. It has a few menuitems:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <--- items here --->
</menu>
```

My BottomNavigationView:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_menu_layout"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#D3D3D3" />

    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
```

my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:include="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainlayouttext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/maintextview"
        include:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        include:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        include:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        include:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <include layout="@layout/meny_bottom_layout" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your include does not specify any `constraints` . If I were in you, I would try something like

```
    <include
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"  
            layout="@layout/meny_bottom_layout"/>
```

`android:layout_height` and  `android:layout_width` are mandatory if you want the other included parameter to be taken in consideration

Comment: Thanks! I changed width&height to wrap_content and added the bottom_toBottonOf constraint and it is in place now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Blackbelt can i have your email?

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:menu="@menu/bottombar_menu"/>
```

Create a new **bottombar_menu.xml** under …res/menu/.

**bottombar_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

 <item
    android:id="@+id/bottombaritem_calls"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_call_24dp"
    android:title="Calls"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

you can try like this